# Rails - Multiple select_tag under the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form in a view called example.erb, which looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:action => "xyz"), :method => 'get' do %>
```

In this form, there are two separate select tags which will post in url with same parameter id:

```
<%= select_tag "id" ...{Rest of code}... %>
<%= select_tag "id" ...{Rest of code}..., selected_item %>
```

selected_item is a default parameter for the second select_tag when no option is selected. When the form submits, sometimes it looks fine. However, sometimes in url it looks like this:

```
id=123&id=456&...{Rest of url}...
```

What I want, is when one of the options in the first select_tag is selected, it only pass the id of the item and ignore the second select_tag no matter what its value set to. Also, the two select_tags must be placed in the same form and isolate them into two form is not practical. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I have found a potential solution. When the form is about to submit, just set  the second select_tag to be disabled. In this way, the item in the second select_tag will not be submitted. I am still testing it and wondering if there is any side-effect.

Comment: the last `select_tag` will always over-write the value of the previous one because, as you said, they share the same `name` in the parameters. Either change the name of one of the `select_tag` or use Javascript to disable all the `select_tag` with `id` as name except for the last that has been changed. IMO you'd be better to change the name(s)

Comment: Why do you need two select tags for the same attribute? If you want to group the options, HTML/Rails supports this. If you want to default on a nil value, that's best handled on the server side IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Actually I have to use it in this way because they are both essentially submitting the same id and the first of the select_tags is a duplication for the second one. Thus I have to make them look like each other in order for the backend to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. By using JS to disable the second select_tag when submitting the form, the first select_tag will always has its id submitted.